# Google Classroom test account cannot access Drive

Tags: google-drive-api, google-classroom

I am currently working on a project involving both the Classroom and Google Drive APIs. However, the Google Classroom test accounts provided by Google do not have access to Google Drive. Is there a way to gain permission to access both of these APIs with a test account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [documentation on test accounts](https://developers.google.com/classroom/access), they do not have access to applications other than Classroom, which does include Drive and therefore the Drive API. However, [Google just announced](https://blog.google/topics/education/google-classroom-outside-classroom/) that you can no use Classroom with personal accounts (@gmail.com), which would provide an alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try using [Google Application Default Credentials](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials) which provide a simple way to get authorization credentials for use in calling Google APIs. These also provide a way of using alternative credentials when testing out the application prior to deployment.

In addition to that, it was also mentioned in [Authenticating applications with a client library](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/create-enable-service-accounts-for-instances#clientlib) that application default credentials allow applications to obtain credentials from multiple sources so you can test your application locally and then deploy it to a Compute Engine instance without changing the application code.

You may want to check the the given links for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I think this will really help in working with both Drive and Classroom APIs simultaneously. I do have one question though. What I'd really like to do is create a classroom assignment with an attachment from Drive via API calls, but as far as I can tell I can't get those permissions on my project since I don't have an account with access to both services. Can I use Default Credentials to solve this issue?